# Setting up rxSwift with a text field?

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

I am using rxSwift for the first time, I have a textfield in my View, I want to set its value to the viewModels property that corresponds. I have the following code but it throws errors. What am I missing here?

```
self.loginView.emailTextField.rx.text
            .bindTo(self.loginViewModel.userEmail)
            .addDisposableTo(self.disposeBag)
```

Issue:

> Cannot invoke 'bindTo' with an argument list of type '(String)'

Comment: Is userEmail normal String? You cannot bind Observables to normal primitive types

Comment: Can you show the view model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've used String type for userEmail in your ViewModel. You cannot bind observable to normal String. Your view model type should look like this:

```
var userEmail = Variable<String>("")
```

and now from the ViewController you can bind like this:

```
emailTextField.rx.text.orEmpty
    .bind(to: viewModel.userEmail)
    .addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
```

Also if you want to use optional string you can also do it like this:

```
var userEmail = Variable<String?>(nil)
emailTextField.rx.text.bind(to: viewModel.userEmail)
```

Comment: Value of type 'Binder<String?>' has no member 'bind'